# xpages displaying a message if field value is already in a list

Tags: xpages

There is an inputText - string ( representing company name ): `txt_NumeCompanie`
Let's suppose there are already 2 docs. saved having the above field value: `ABC` and `Xpages`.

What I want to do:

1. If I create a new doc. and I complete the company name field with `ABC` or `Xpages`, a message to appear letting me know a document exists already having that name.
2. If I open the document having `Xpages` as the company name and I'm changing it to `ABC` again the above message.

What I've tried: the `onChange` event of the field refreshes a panel which contains a `<xp:div styleClass="lotusMessage"`. This div has the following rendered property:

```
     if ( currentDocument.isNewNote())
{
if ( @IsMember(Cdoc.getItemValueString("txt_NumeCompanie"),@Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(),"vwComp",0))) )
    { return true;}
     else { return false; }
} 
else
{   
var newe = Cdoc.getItemValueString("txt_NumeCompanie");   
if ( @IsMember(newe,@Unique(@DbLookup(@DbName(),"vwCompanii",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID(),2))) ) 
    { return false;}
     else { return true; }
}
```

The `vwCompanii` is having one column listing all the `txt_NumeCompanie` values and `vwCompanii` is having 2 columns: `@Text(@DocumentUNiqueID))` and `txt_NumeCompanie`'. The above code works fine for .isNewNote() documents.But, if I opened an existing doc. ( having txt_NumeCompanie = ABC ) the message appears again, without changing anything. I do want to cover also the 2. case from the above item list.

Also, by opening an existing doc. from the viewPanel, when the doc. is opened and displayed, the script message appears immediately even if the value of `txt_NumeCompanie` hadn't been changed. How can I make the script message to be fired only when the onChange event is taking place, and not when the document is opened?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

@DbColumn checking won't work for you here. The method to take is to access the NotesView, then look for a document matching the key, then check whether that document has a different UNID to the current document.

It's a common requirement, which is why for the latest release of OpenNTF Domino API I added View.checkUnique(key, srcDoc), see https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/blob/master/org.openntf.domino/src/org/openntf/domino/impl/View.java#L2645-2663. (Line numbers will have changed in future releases). Bear in mind this code relies on constructs in the core of OpenNTF Domino API, like easy iteration, auto-recycling etc.

Comment: What if I will try with a DbLookup having 1st column the UNID and the 2nd column the field value?

Comment: It may work, but my recommendation is to use the Domino Object Model, so NotesView and NotesViewEntry / NotesDocument. It performs better, is better suited for looping checks, and will better support future development. Most of the people answering XPages questions use Domino Object Model rather than @Formulas, because Domino Object Model is available from Java and the methods perform the same. Extended APIs like OpenNTF Domino API also don't tend to focus on adding '@Formula' because of the effort involved to provide an additional wrapper - one wrapper is already required to allow SSJS access

Comment: You CAN use DbLookup with [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID] param - if you find the key and UNIDs match, you can go. No unids column needed, @florin.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Could you give me an example of how to use [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID] for a document having the key ( txt_NumeCompanie ) given? Also, should the view be categorized or sorted?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is simple: lookup document by key value and allow to save it if and only if:

- for new document, there is no such key
- for saved document, there is exactly one key used in current document (unids match).

Snippet:

```
try {
    var unid = @DbLookup("", "view", "key", 1, '[RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]');
    if (unid && unid instanceof String) {
        if (doc.isNewNote()) {
            // key was found, that's bad
            return false; //(do not continue)
        } else {
            return unid == doc.getUniversalID();
        }
    } else if (!unid) {
        return true; // key not found, it's unique, go
    } else {
        return false; // duplicates found
    }
}
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html

Comment: I've added this in my rendered property, but still no working: var unid = @DbLookup("", "vwComp", Cdoc.txt_NumeCompanie, 1, '[RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]');
    if (unid && unid instanceof String) {
        if (doc.isNewNote()) {
            // key was found, that's bad
            return false; //(do not continue)
        } else {
            return unid == doc.getUniversalID();
        }
    } 
    
    else if (!unid) {
        return true; // key not found, it's unique, go
    } else {
        return false; // duplicates found
    }

Comment: I just want to use this code for a div/scriptBlock, and for its rendered property, not for the saving method of the document.

Comment: It is very bad practice to put @Db functions in rendered property - it clones easily. Returns with true/false should work with rendered property too. Do you refresh parent container to recompute it?

Comment: Yep, I do refresh the panel for recomputing. This issue gives me headache, alongside with the other last question. Hope to get it work.

Comment: Using the above code, my scriptblock is always hidden. I try showing the returned unid with: view.postscript("alert(unid)");, but no dialog is showed.

Comment: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2013/947

Comment: Shouldn't be doc.getDocument().getUniversalID() instead of doc.getUniversalID() ?

Comment: I'm sorry, your code doesn't work for my issue / specification